# Sql search multiple values on multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-columns

In an sql table like:

```
Name        |Description
------------------------
Animal      | Dog
Animal      | Wolf
Zoo_animal  | Dog
```

Is there a way to obtain values from column "Name" that meet two specific criteria on other column, "Description".

All the entries for "Name" where the description is = Dog or = Wolf on different rows (so return "Animal", which has the values Dog and Wolf in different rows), but not if only one criteria is true (Zoo_animal, which only has the value Dog).

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Oracle, I tried simple query with OR clauses for each literal and check visually the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select name
from t
where description in ('dog', 'wolf')
group by name
having count(distinct description) = 2;
```